# How to use Nlntegrate if I only have its NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations

Known $\frac{d\phi}{da}=a$, how to calculate $\int^{1.6}_{0.4} \phi^{2}(a) da$?

I've tried something like

```
s = NDSolve[{ϕ'[a] == a, ϕ[1] == 1}, ϕ, {a, 0.4, 1.6}];

Nlntegrate[ϕ[a]* ϕ[a] /. s[[1]], {a, 0.4, 1.6} ]
```

but it doesn't output a number.

(The true formula is more complex so I used numerical solution here.)

Comment: You misspelled `NIntegrate`. If you fix that, your code returns 1.49578.

Comment: In addition to the typo, slight simplification: `s = NDSolveValue[{phi'[a] == a, phi[1] == 1}, phi, {a, 0.4, 1.6}];
NIntegrate[s[a]^2, {a, 0.4, 1.6}]`

Answer (score 3):

I prefer including the desired [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) output right into the [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve):

```
{s, integral} = NDSolveValue[
    {
    ϕ'[a] == 1, ϕ[1] == 1, 
    int'[a] == ϕ[a]^2, int[1] == 0
    },
    {ϕ, int},
    {a, .4, 1.6}
];
```

Compare:

```
integral[1.6] - integral[.4]
NIntegrate[s[a]^2, {a, .4, 1.6}]
```

> 1.344
>
> 1.344

Another variant that outputs the result directly:

```
{s, integral} = NDSolveValue[
    {
    ϕ'[a] == 1, ϕ[1] == 1, 
    int'[a] == ϕ[a]^2, int[1] == 0
    },
    {ϕ, int[1.6]-int[.4]},
    {a, .4, 1.6}
]
```

> {InterpolatingFunction[Domain: {{0.4,1.6}}
>   Output: scalar
>   ],1.344}

Comment: Slick...(actually when I saw this question I thought "Carl will have something different to show here")